# React-Native Build-Failed

Tags: react-native

When running "npx react-native run-android":

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'D:\Coding\New folder\MHLSLEAGUE\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\tamer.gradle\caches\8.0.1\scripts\73fo79rs4o85yhjvff7lwhytg).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 64

---

right before that:

i Changed the "BuildToolsVersion" in the build.gradle to '33.0.0' instead of findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '33.0.0'
because of the react-native doctor error
[✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android

- Versions found: 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 33.0.0
- Version supported: .b33.0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjdv0.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

For Linux/Mac OS:

Go to Terminal:

```
~ cd home

~ cd yourDirectory   //eg:ashif

~ cd Android

~ cd cd build-tools

~ cd 33.0.0         //your desired build-tools version

~ cp d8 dx          //copy d8 and create directory dx

~ cd lib

~ cp d8.jar dx.jar  //copy d8.jar and create directory dx.jar

~ ls                //to list and check the changes
```

For Windows:

```
~ Go to Home Directory/Folder    //where the Android dir is present eg: inside C://

~ Inside click android dir

~ Inside click Sdk dir

~ Inside click build-tools dir

~ Inside click desired directory 33.0.0   //your desired build-tools version

~ Inside that, copy the d8 folder paste it in the same location, and rename it as dx

~ Inside And click lib dir

~ Inside copy d8.jar and paste it in the same location and rename it as dx.jar
```

**That's it! It Works .**